# Can github be used to serve XML?

Tags: xml, github

I have some XML in github. If I curl and save the file locally

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/geojayuu/bookmarks/master/bookmarks_xbel.xml > local.xml
```

I can then open the file in FireFox and it renders using the standard xml stylesheet.

If I try to do the same thing directly from github using the raw page

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/geojayuu/bookmarks/master/bookmarks_xbel.xml

it renders as what looks like plain text.

What I'd like to be able to do is point to the raw xml on github and have it render in my browser like a local file with the same content does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out the [**raw.githack.com**](https://raw.githack.com/) service.

In your case, the url to use would be:
https://rawcdn.githack.com/geojayuu/bookmarks/master/bookmarks_xbel.xml

As its name alludes to, it is an hack (which depends on the existence of the githack.com service).
The problem is in the content-type served by `raw.githubusercontent.com`: it is not set.
`raw.githack.com` does set it: `Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8`

Comment: Cool, thanks for that. I wasn't intending this to be for a production cause nor is there anything sensitive in the data so this should work fine.